# Show Requests and Bugs links in left sidebar

Tags: feature-request, meta, navigation

It's not obvious when you go to https://meta.stackexchange.com how to add a feature request or bug report - clicking on `Ask Question` is counter-intuitive - it takes some digging around on the site to figure out how to do it.

Another option would be to have a small section in the right sidebar explaining how to post feature requests and bugs.

A section could be also added to the Help page - I couldn't find anything there - https://meta.stackexchange.com/help.

Another possibility would be to say "Top Questions/Requests/Bugs" instead of just "Top Questions" and/or "Post Question/Request/Bug" instead of "Ask Question".

I know there are the Bugs/Reqs filters in the header, but I didn't notice them until much later, and even then there's no guidance, you just need to notice that you would include the relevant tag in your question.

Comment: Better idea:  have the "Ask Question" button send you to a new page explaining about bug reports and feature requests when it's your first question.

Comment: @ShadowWizard My initial impression when coming here was that I would need to go elsewhere to post a feature request, as Ask Question seems like it would only be for questions. So I searched the Help, and then started writing a question about where to post feature requests before finding a similar question that answered it.

Comment: Well, what you went through is normal, IMO, but I agree it can be improved.